# Solution for GIT commits in Visual Studio while Unity is open?

Tags: c#, unity, visual-studio, git

**Specifications**

-VS 2013 Pro (Linked with Unity)

-Unity 4.6.1

-Git Version Control (Linked with Visual Studio 2013)

**Summary**

After much research, I haven't found any solutions to this fix.
*While visual studio 2013 and Unity 4.6.1 is open, I am unable to commit in Visual Studio in Team Explorer. I am able to SYNC and commit when VS is closed.

ERROR: An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open 'PROJECT/Temp/UnityLockfile': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I understand that it is being used, but is there any work around to this? I need to write custom commit messages to close open ISSUES in git, but would be efficient if done while Unity is open.

This just slows me down in terms of product management/ workflow, so if anyone has any workarounds to commit while unity is open, it would be much appreciated.

Let me  know if you have any questions, I know there are some Unity/VS/Git masters out there

FIXED SOLUTION:
Only include ProjectSettings and Assets when committing->
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solution-for-git-commits-in-vs-while-unity-is-open.328380/

Comment: are you trying to commit the lock file?Never commit from inside VS, but in general there's nothing preventing you to keep unity open and using git.

Comment: Highly recommend against committing your temp directory. Source control should include raw code, assets, and project settings only.

Comment: I'll try only committing ProjectSettings and Assets, that's probably the issue. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solution-for-git-commits-in-vs-while-unity-is-open.328380/